# multithreaded urllib2 freezes on nose framework

Tags: python, nose

I have a python code that uses nose_parameterized as below:

```
from nose_parameterized import parameterized
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import urllib2

def make_http_call(url, req_type):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener() # <=== this line causes it to freeze
    return 1

pool = ThreadPool(processes=4)
results = []
urls = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for url in urls:
    results.append(pool.apply_async(make_http_call, (url, 'html')))
d = {'add': []}
for ind, res in enumerate(results):
    d['add'].append((res.get(), 2+ind, 3+ind))

@parameterized(d['add'])
def test_add(a, b, c):
    assert a+b == c
```

This is the dummy version of the code. Basically, I need to load test parameters with http request responses and since there are lots of urls, I want to multithread them.
As soon as I add urllib2.build_opener, it freezes up using nose (but still works fine with python)
Also, I've tried urllib2.urlopen; the same problem.
Any ideas whether there is 'proper' (debuggable) a way to work around this?

Comment: Maybe this will [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137187/python-process-blocked-by-urllib2)

Comment: Thanks. I know about that problem that you linked but I cannot put anything inside a __main__ not in the nose setup since the setup is executed after the parameter gathering. Given the limitations, I was hoping for a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nose [multiprocess](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/multiprocess.html) built in plugin for that, something like:

```
from nose_parameterized import parameterized
import urllib2

urls = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com']

@parameterized(urls)
def test_add(url):
    a = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

    b = 2 + urls.index(url)
    c = 3 + urls.index(url)
    assert a+str(b) == str(c)
```

and run it with `nosetests --processes=2`. This enables you to distribute your test run among a set of worker processes that run tests in parallel as you intended. Behind the scenes, multiprocessing module is used.

Comment: Thanks.This answers the question. If I load the data inside the test method, I will be forced to do all assertions there rather than in separate test methods. Another issue is that I also have some tests that cannot be run in parallel which means I need separate nose runs...regardless, it's good to know about this feature.